# Why ssh-copy-id copies public key when adding it to authorized_keys seems enough?

Tags: ssh

A colleague of mine told me he could SSH into a server where his key is only listed in authorized_keys. I was surprised and wondered why ssh-copy-id copies the key to the server then ?

Answer (score 0):

Because that is how you would let a client connect to the server via `Public Key Authentication`.

`ssh-copy-id` is a script that installs a public key on a remote machine via ssh. Basically what it does is append the public key to the remote machine's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (see `ssh-copy-id` man page for more details). It can be useful especially if you do not have physical access to the machine.

But of course, since the public key you would like to use wouldn't be installed on the target server yet, you would have to log in with an already available authentication method like login password, preventing potential malicious users from adding their own public key.

Comment: Please close off-topic questions. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.